# Editing 3dpolyline and an arc

Tags: autocad

I have a 3dpolyline and arc (3D). I 'm wondering if I can join 3dpolyline with 3d arc to get 3dpolyline. While seraching on this topic i found that I need first a routine that converts arc to 3dpolyline and then join two 3dpolylines. Does some one knows some link.?

Answer (score 1):

A 3D polyline is a connected sequence of straight line segments created as a single object. 3D polylines can be non-coplanar; however, they cannot include arc segments.

http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f48755-471cc4bd11960d8a16c-1c8.htm,topicNumber=d0e290136